# Postgres - Order by 2 fields contemporary

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I've got a problem with an order by.

I have this table

`|desc|phone|calls|group|priority|
|cccc|12347|700|13247|0|
|aaaa|12345|900|12345|0|
|bbbb|12346|500|12345|1|`

I need to order this table for calls respecting the group, so my result should be

`|desc|phone|calls|group|priority|
|aaaa|12345|900|12345|0|
|bbbb|12346|500|12345|1|
|cccc|12347|700|13247|0|`

because bbbb is with the same group of aaaa.

How can I do this?

Thanks

EDIT:
Hi all,
sorry if my question is unclear, next time I'll be more specific.
Yes, I need to order this table for calls respecting the group, like if bbbb doesn't exists

Comment: _I need to order this table for calls respecting the group_ ?? can you be more specific ??

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is a bit unclear, An order by is enough

```
select * from sample order by "group"
```

[sqlfiddle-demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fcec1/1)